# VBA - Compile error: Expected: If or Select or Sub or Function or Property or Type or With or Enum or end of statement

Tags: ms-access, while-loop, vba, compiler-warnings

Forgive me for the noob question. Working in VBA is not my normal job.

I get the error listed in the title. The offending code is this:

```
While index <= 10
    index = index + 1
End While
```

I can't imagine what could be wrong with that, seeing that it is copied directly from the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/while-end-while-statement

Seeing that the code can't be the problem, I'm supposing the problem must be something in the context, but before I put this block in, it was working fine.

This block of code is part of a simple, private subroutine which declares a variable, assign a value to it, and then writes it into a file, like so:

```
Private Sub btnExpAll_Click()
Dim sFldr As String
sFldr = BrowseFolder("Where do you want to export the files?") 
If sFldr = "" Then Exit Sub                                    
DoCmd.Hourglass True

Dim sListLocal As String
Dim index As Integer

Dim strInputFileNameLocal As String

sListLocal = ""

index = 0

While index <= 10
    index = index + 1
End While

strInputFileNameLocal = sFldr & "\list-local.html"

Open strInputFileNameLocal For Output As #1
Print #1, sListLocal
Close #1

DoCmd.Hourglass False

End Sub
```

The idea is to add more text to the file as we go through the while loop based on certain conditions - but since I can't even get the while loop to compile...

Comment: `Do While index <= 10: statementsHere: Loop`

Comment: `While...Wend` is an obsolete loop construct. Use `Do While...Loop` instead. That way you can do `Exit Do` (can't jump out of `While...Wend` without a `GoTo`)

Comment: The documentation you're looking at is VB.NET, not VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link referenced in question is VB.net example, which has similarities to VBA and in some simple examples, easily confused. Replace `End While` with `Wend` or use `Do … Loop` structure.

Review: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-while-loop/